# Get User Rank Based on Sum with Pagination

Tags: mysql, sum, rank

There are several rank posts out there but I have yet to see one dealing with when the results are paginated and when the ranking criteria (in this case: points) is equal to the previous user. I have tried a few of the pre-existing examples but none have worked.

I have a table called "users" with the column "id". I also have a table called "points" with the columns "user_id" and "amount".

**I need:**

1.) Users with duplicate sum of points to have the same rank

Points Table

```
user_id     amount
   1          10
   2          20
   1           5
   3          20
   3          -5
   4          5
```

Rank should be

```
rank     user_id    total
 1          2        20
 2          1        15
 2          3        15
 3          4        5
```

2.) Needs to maintain the ranking from one page to another so the rank has to be gathered in the query and not the resulting PHP.

3.) Display ALL users not just ones with rows in the points table because some users have 0 points and I want to display them last.

Right now I'm just listing the users in order of their points but their rank is not gathered because it wasn't working.

```
$getfanspoints = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT id,
(SELECT SUM(amount) AS points FROM points WHERE points.user_id = users.id) AS points
FROM users
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT $offset, $fans_limit", $conn);
```

I've read these solutions and none have worked.

[Roland's Blog][1]

[How to get rank based on SUM's][2]

[MySQL, get users rank][3]

[How to get rank using mysql query][4]

and a few others whose link I can't find right now.

**Any suggestions?**

***[EDIT]***

I used ypercube's bottom answer.

Comment: Just a side note: if you show the ranks more than you change them, it would be worth thinking about denormalizing your tables and storing the sum of points for every user in the users table. Update it only when a user gets some points, instead of recalculating it for every page render.

Comment: I think that will be difficult to do with my situation as users earn and lose points rapidly but points are also sort of "in queue", there is a delay between when the points are rewarded and when they can actually use their points for stuff. Also each point is tied to a specific action. The points table also includes the columns page_id, module_id, post_id, group_id, item_id, other_users. They earn and lose points for different activities and a log of it is displayed on their profile and in the user dashboard. Hard to explain but I do not feel it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
     , t.user_id
     , t.total 
FROM
      ( SELECT   user_id
             ,   SUM(amount) AS total
        FROM     points 
        GROUP BY user_id
      ) AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 SUM(amount) AS total
        FROM     points 
        GROUP BY user_id
      ) AS dt
    ON 
        t.total <= dt.total
GROUP BY t.user_id
ORDER BY rank
       , user_id
```

---

But the above may be really slow with a big table and points awarded often. It might be really better to have just this and calculate the ranks in your application code:

```
SELECT   users.id    AS user_id
     ,   SUM(amount) AS total
FROM     
         users
  LEFT JOIN
         points
    ON   points.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY total DESC
       , user_id
```

---

This will work, too (edited, to work with the `users` table and with `OFFSET`):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT
          @rank := @rank + (@t <> total) AS rank
        , user_id 
        , @t := total AS total
    FROM 
        ( SELECT   users.id AS user_id
               ,   COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS total
          FROM users
            LEFT JOIN points
              ON users.id = points.user_id
          GROUP BY users.id
        ) AS o
      CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT @rank := 0, @t := -999999
        ) AS dummy
    ORDER BY total DESC
           , user_id
  ) tmp
LIMIT x OFFSET y
```

Comment: none of the solutions work, no error message just returns 0 results. Why would it be selecting the SUM(amount) AS total FROM users instead of from points?

Comment: it wasn't working :( but I think I might of just gotten it. Check above.

Comment: It needs some adjustment (one more LEFT JOIN) to show also the users without points.

Comment: again, 0 results are returned

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7006/discussion-between-ypercube-and-bowlerae)